# #<IO:<STDOUT>> received :puts with unexpected arguments - Random number and Rspec issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So im currently using the Learn.co gem in which I am trying to solve a blackjack lab. https://github.com/learn-co-curriculum/simple-blackjack-cli
The following Rspec code expects a specific output which confuses me since we working with random numbers. Here is the Rspec code:

```html
describe "#runner" do

  before(:each) do
    def get_user_input
      "h"
    end 
  end

  it "calls on the #welcome method, 
  then on the #initial_round method, 
  then calls #hit? and #display_card_total methods
  -until- the card sum is greater than 21,
  then calls on the #end_game method" do

    expect(self).to receive(:deal_card).at_least(3).times.and_return(10)
    expect(self).to receive(:get_user_input).and_return("h")

    expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("Welcome to the Blackjack Table")
    expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("Your cards add up to 20")
    expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("Type 'h' to hit or 's' to stay")
    expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("Your cards add up to 30")
    expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("Sorry, you hit 30. Thanks for playing!")
    runner
  end
end
```

But since we using random numbers in the following code, how can it be the exact output of Rspec. Here is the Ruby code:

```html
def welcome
  # code #welcome here
  puts "Welcome to the Blackjack Table"
end

def deal_card
  randomNumber = rand(1..11)
end

def display_card_total(total_cards)
  
  puts "Your cards add up to #{total_cards}"
  return total_cards
end

def prompt_user
  puts "Type 'h' to hit or 's' to stay"
end

def get_user_input
  letter = gets.chomp
end

def end_game(card_total)
  puts "Sorry, you hit #{card_total}. Thanks for playing!"
end

def initial_round
  initOne = deal_card()
  initTwo = deal_card()
  sumInit = initOne + initTwo
  display_card_total(sumInit)

end

def hit?(myNumber)
  prompt_user()
  result = get_user_input()
  card_total = myNumber
    if result == 's'
      return myNumber 
    elsif result == 'h'
      sumInit = myNumber + deal_card()
      return sumInit
    else
      invalid_command()
    end
end

def invalid_command
  puts "Please enter a valid command"
end

#####################################################
# get every test to pass before coding runner below #
#####################################################

def runner
 welcome()
 number = initial_round()
  until number > 21
   hit?(number)
   display_card_total(number)
  number += hit?(number)
  end
  end_game(number)
end
```

How can the output match the Rspec test if we dealing with random numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The following code in the runner method fixed the problem.

```html
def runner
 welcome()
 number = initial_round()
  until number > 21
  
  number = hit?(number)
  display_card_total(number)
  end
  end_game(number)
end
```